# Automate AppArmor modification

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, automation, puppet, apparmor

I need to change the AppArmor configuration by allowing it to read/write from a directory.

I added the necessary line in `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld` as mentioned in the documentation and then run `aa-logprof` to allow the modification. It works.

Now I want to automate that using Puppet, however I can't find a non-interactive mode for `aa-logprof`. What is the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good starting point for ya: [Puppet Augeas](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#augeas)